# Improving the quality of TIFF images

Tags: c#, jpeg, tiff

We have a around 600,000 images that were converted from JPEG to TIFF files and uploaded to our FileNet repository. These TIFF images are multi-page, made by stitching multiple JPEGs.

This was done couple of years ago. Now we started getting complaints from users the quality of the TIFF images are not the same as they were when they were JPEGs.

Is there any way we can improve the quality of TIFF files? If I have to re-migrate this data, can JPEGs be of multiple pages? Please advice.

Comment: When you compare the `TIFF` and `JPEG` versions of a specific file what quality differences do you notice? Can you post little tiny snippets of the images that clearly demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just add quality to an image, so you can either try improving the appearance of the *current* information or you'll need to re-create the images to get *better* information.

To me, it sounds like the initial creation process is the most likely cause of the quality issue.  How you create the image is important.

For example, I had a large number of photos I needed to re-size, so I used irfanview's batch convert and the results were horrible.  Perhaps I had the settings wrong, I don't know.
I then tried using ImageMagick, and the results were great.
The point being, the conversion process isn't trivial.

If I were you, I'd look at how the images were created, experiment with different settings to determine what gives the best appearance, then re-create your photo gallery.

For photographic material, there's no real reason to use anything other than a jpeg if the target market is the general consumer.

Answer (score 2):

Both TIFF and JPEG support lossless and lossy storage of your images. You mentioned that there was a previous conversion. The conversion was probably a lossy conversion as such you probably won't be able to recover that data to the way it was previously.

That said if you have the original source images you might be able to get back to where you where. Regarding multi-image jpegs, there is such a format *.mpo but I haven't seen it used before so your millage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You probably converted gray scale or color Jpeg to Tiff.  The most common is Tiff G4 which is only 1 bit per pixel.  So 24 or 8 bits was converted to 1 bit and you will see a lot of images losses.  There are multiple methods to improve image quality but I would have to see the images first to suggest a method.